# SDL C++ Linker Error

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-ttf

I'm trying to get the ttf SDL fonts up and running on my machine.

I'm using CodeBlocks and have the appropriate linking already to build a standard SDL window: 
-lSDL -lSDL_main without any problems.

I have read from wikipedia and other sources just to confirm I am supposed to link with -lSDL_ttf and I included this in my IDE linking options after -lSDLmain and -lSDL and get the error:

```
ld.exe||cannot find -lSDL_ttf|
||=== Build finished: 1 errors, 0 warnings ===|
```

I have extracted the headers and files that come with the download for it to my SDL subdirectory in my compiler and I don't understand what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Please give some more detail on what is going on here. You say that -lSDL is working but not -lSDL_ttf? That means that you're compiler is finding the SDL library but not the SDL_ttf. Are you sure you have the SDL_ttf library somewhere (dll)? Try getting it from here http://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_ttf/

EDIT: Which compiler are you using? Did you try specifying "-L." so that it will search in the current directory? Can you give us the full linker command you are executing?

Comment: You are correct, I have the SDL_ttf .dll file in my Win32 and put it in the compiling folder just to make sure it should be able to find it. Alas I still get the cannot find error.