# SDL C++ ttf linker errors

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-ttf

I'm using CodeBlocks and trying to link SDL_ttf when compiling my program. I have followed thus instructions:

```
Add "-lSDL_ttf" in the linker command line
Put SDL_ttf.dll in library directory
Put SDL_ttf.h in include file directory
```

And I have this error when compiling:

```
ld.exe||cannot find -lSDL_ttf|
||=== Build finished: 1 errors, 0 warnings ===|
```

I've tried so many methods to solve this and I feel like banging my head against a brick wall.

I'm running Windows and I have moved the .dll to my system32 as well as the project folder and put the header files in my compilers includes folder.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SDL C++ Linker Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7823586/sdl-c-linker-error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need the `.lib` file to link against.  Put the `.lib` file in your library directory; you may also need to add that directory to your linker's search path with the `-L <path>` option.

Comment: The download comes with no .lib files. I am confused now: I got the download from the official site: http://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_ttf/

Comment: Which archive did you download?  The file `SDL_ttf-devel-2.0.10-VC.zip` does indeed contain a lib file at the path `SDL_ttf-2.0.10/lib/SDL_ttf.lib`.

Comment: I downloaded the win32 one above it. Wasted all my time when it was in another download file as well as your time!

Comment: I have no errors now, the program will compile fine, thank you

Answer (score 2):

you have to use -lSDL2_ttf instead -lSDL_ttf